# Do there exist smooth genus-1 surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ admitting vector fields with integral curves posessing everywhere normal curvature $>0 $?

Tags: differential-geometry

The question is a mouthful, but here's the jist: I was idly daydreaming about walking on a toroidal planet, and how if I was walking around the "hole" of the planet, no matter where on my path I might be, it would always seem that my path was bending away from the ground. That seemed somewhat remarkable, but also quite specific. This only works on the inside-side of a torus, not the outside. It got me thinking about a more generalized situation, which I'll state mathematically below:

Does there exist some compact surface $\Sigma$ homeomorphic to a torus and compatible $C^2$-continuous vector field $V$ such that for every parametrizable integral curve $C(t)$ of $V$, the normal curvature $k_n>0$ for all points on all curves?

I feel like the existence of these surfaces and vector fields can be quickly disproven with some application of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, or something else, but I haven't been able to put the pieces together.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> If we pick the opposite ("outward") normal to the one you considered, the same paths (namely, meridians/longitudes) serve. Are you fixing the normal field to point toward the compact interior of the torus?